# Update textbox by navigating DataGridView with arrow keys

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, textbox, keydown

```
public delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e);
public event MyEventHandler SomethingHappened;    

private void dataGridViewCargo_CellContentClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        DataGridViewRow rowID = this.dataGridViewCargo.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        cargoDisplayMessageIdTextBox.Text = rowID.Cells["iDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString();

        DataGridViewRow rowSender = this.dataGridViewCargo.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        cargoDisplaySubjectTextBox.Text = rowSender.Cells["subjectDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString();

    }
}



protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    Invoke(new MyEventHandler(SomethingHappened));
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

The first part updates my textbox's when I select the row. The second part is an attempt at an event handler. I want to to update the textboxes just by navigating the grid with keyboard. So whatever row is highlighted in blue automatically populates the textboxes.

I tried to invoke an event handler by including it in dataGridViewCargo_CellContentClick but sender and e don't pass through and I get Parameter Count Mismatch error or Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'. The idea was to call the CellContentClick event by pressing a button.

Any help would be very kind.

Comment: CellContentClick is isually a bad choice as you have to hit the actual content. why do you have to ProcessCmdKey? The dgv should do the stuff all by itself unless it is disabeled. Just code the CurrentCellChanged event!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use mouse or arrow keys to move between rows of your `DataGridView` is data-bound, the position of its data source changes and all controls which are bound to the same data source will show values from new position.

Also if you don't use data-binding the `SelectionChanged` event of `DataGridView` will be raised and can be used to update controls.

So you can use either of these options to solve the problem:

- Bind those `TextBox` controls to the same data source which `DataGridView` uses.
- Use `SelectionChanged` event of `DataGridView`.

If you bind `DataGridView` to a `DataSource`, then you can simply use data-binding for your `TextBox` controls too. It's enough to bind those `TextBox` controls to the fields of data source which you want to show by click on each row. You can perform data-binding using designer or using code:

```
var data = GetDataFromSomeShere();
dataGridViewCargo.DataSource = data;
cargoDisplayMessageIdTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", data, "ID");
cargoDisplaySubjectTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", data, "Subject");
```

If you don't use data-binding, you can simply use `SelectionChanged` event of `DataGridView` and use `CurrentRow` property of `DataGridView` to find those fields and update your `TextBox` control:

```
private void dataGridViewCargo_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var row = dataGridViewCargo.CurrentRow;
    cargoDisplayMessageIdTextBox.Text = 
        row.Cells["iDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString();
    cargoDisplaySubjectTextBox.Text =
        row .Cells["subjectDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString();
}
```

Using data-binding (the first option) is preferred.

Comment: Thank you. I used the suggested data-binding method however I did try to use the SelectionChanged alternative however I don't seem to have a reference to my dataGridViewCargo when I write private void dataGridViewCargo_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e). Do you know why that might be?

Comment: You're welcome. For the second option, you should not forget to attach the event handler to the event using code or designer. Also make sure you write the event handler in a scope which your grid is visible to the method.